# apply function to multiple dataframe in shorter way?

Tags: python, pandas, user-defined-functions

let's say i have multiple dataframe df1, df2,...,df100 and I have function as written below.
I don't know how to apply the function to multiple (a hundred df) in shorter way. any suggestion?
many thanks,

```
def sma(x,length):
   ma = x.rolling(window=length,min_periods=1).mean()
   return (x / ma) -1

sma(df1, 40)
```

Comment: use a list/dictionary to store all dataframes and use: `out = [sma(d, 40) for d in list_of_dfs]` or `out = {k: sma(d, 40) for k, d in dic_of_dfs.items()}`

Comment: okay thanks mozway, after that i just brekadown the list into different dataframe

Comment: You're welcome. I really recommend you to use a dictionary, thus you don't have to manually handle hundred variables!

Comment: Hi mozway, can you give me a simple example to use a dictionary relating to the topic ? or any reference link , so i can study it by myself, thanks in advance

Comment: `dfs = {'A': df1, 'B': df2} ; out = {k: sma(d, 40) for k, d in dfs.items()}`

Comment: it works much better.. thanks mozway